# Upload logo with AJAX and jQuery within a big JS application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I have a huge application in Javascript and other libraries, but now I want to add another feature, adding images via an upload. I´ve found multiple, working examples, but when i try to integrate that in my application nothing happens. Things just don´t work. I´m quite stuck now.

Firstly this is the image upload I found:

http://phppot.com/php/php-ajax-image-upload/

But when I integrate it in my application it just doesnt work.. There aren't any errors in the console.

Maybe a problem is the fact I use multiple POST data to get this right, because I already had a huge POST data  for the whole application. I can't get it working with integrating it all in 1 POST but maybe that is a possibility..

I'm so stuck right now. Here are some of the codes:

This is the part of the JS which get called when pressed on the upload button

```
    jQuery("#uploadForm").submit(function(e) {
    console.log('upload die handel');
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log('upload die handel');
            $("#logouploadtekst").html('Great success!');
            $("#logouploadtekst").append(data);
        },
        error: function() 
        {
            $("#logouploadtekst").html('Great failure!');
        }           
   });
});
```

This is the file which get called...

```
    <?php
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>" />
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

I actually want to send an email with the image with, so I don't really know if it's necessary to upload the image, but I think it's better to do (right?)

EDIT: It seems the the upload.php doesn't work. Can it be that I cannot call 2 different PHP Post scripts? Because First I try to call the upload.php to upload the logo, and then I show it on my page, after that the client finishes the app and presses submit again to send the email. So I do get the console.log in the AJAX call, but the data doesn't get through..

Comment: "Things just don´t work" is a poor description. What are the error messages, what does happen? Did you debug the code? Tell us what happened when you did

Comment: I tried so much. There aren't any error messages, that's the whole problem. The PHP code get's executed but there isn't anything uploaded, I guess because there is so much more code to be executed cause of the application what's already there. The upload never starts, but when I get the code out of the application and just use only the code responsible for uplaoding the image, the image get uploaded perfectly fine. I'm sorry I hasn't been any clearer, but I am struggling with this for such a long time, I'm exhausted.

Comment: Use the divide and conquer approach, try it not within your application, create a little page that all it does is upload a file

Comment: Already did. See above. It all works outside of the application. But when I try to integrate it seems that the upload.php file doesn't get called, or the data doesn't seem to get through. The AJAX call gets completed good, because I get these logs in the console.

Comment: Try using something like firebug or chrome console to check if the ajax call actually reaches the upload.php page.

Comment: @HuubS You need to add some logging to your PHP file to find out where it's breaking. Add a log in every line, logging all variables and return values. Unfortunately, I don't see what the problem is, you just have to test it line by line. Did you check that there are files being copied to your upload location in PHP, It's likely that you can't just have an image pointing directly to your uploaded image path, you have to move it to a place that is mapped to be visible from the web, so it's likely not the same path that you copied it into (an internal server path)